Disable cellEditor
<p-cellEditor style="width: 100%;">
  <ng-template pTemplate="input">
    <p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="object.amount" name="chargedAmount" mode="currency" currency="PHP" [disabled]="disableFieldEdit" />
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{ object.amount | currency: 'PHP'}}</ng-template>
</p-cellEditor>

I already added disableFieldEdit, the problem is that the field display is not visible as disable with a grey color. I need to click the field in order to see if its disabled

You can't disable a p-cellEditor, you should instead use a ngIf directive in order to display a p-cellEditor in case your cell is editable, otherwise you display a static cell
<p-cellEditor style="width: 100%;" *ngIf="canEditCell;else staticCell">
  <ng-template pTemplate="input">
    <p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="object.amount" name="chargedAmount" mode="currency" currency="PHP" [disabled]="disableFieldEdit" />
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="output">
    {{ object.amount | currency: 'PHP'}}
  </ng-template>
</p-cellEditor>
<ng-template #staticCell>
  {{ rowData[col.field] }}
</ng-template>




.p-cell-editor.ui-state-disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}



This targets the p-cellEditor element when disabled and reduces its opacity, making it appear greyed out without needing additional code changes.
